# How can I see if a subreddit requires some amount of (1) link and (2) comment karma before posting?

Tags: reddit

Pls, answer for both (1) link and (2) comment karma.

It's bothersome to get an automated message that either my link and/or comment karma is too low AFTER I posted something.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: there is no way of knowing a sub's posting rules, unless they have explicitly listed them somewhere.

Most rules, such as what can be posted and minimum karma/age requirements, are managed by a tool called [AutoModerator](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/automoderator). This is a script that checks posts after they are posted, which is why you'll get an automated message after rather than before posting.

Because the AutoMod rules aren't public, the only way to discover rules is if they are posted in the sub's sidebar/about page/sticky or by making a post.